# ASP .Net Core: Many-to-Many relationship and AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, many-to-many, automapper

I have 2 entities connected by a many to many relationship.

First class:

```
 public class ArticleCategory
 {
        public int Id {get; set; }

        public string MainCategoryName { get; set; }

        public List<ArticleCategorySubcategory> ArticleCategorySubcategories { get; set; } = new List<ArticleCategorySubcategory>();

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
 }
```

Second class:

```
 public class ArticleSubcategory
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    
        public string SubcategoryName { get; set; }

        public List<ArticleCategorySubcategory> ArticleCategorySubcategories { get; set; } = new List<ArticleCategorySubcategory>();
 }
```

And relationship (many to many):

```
 public class ArticleCategorySubcategory : BaseHistoryEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ArticleCategoryId { get; set; }

        public ArticleCategory ArticleCategory { get; set; }

        public int ArticleSubcategoryId { get; set; }

        public ArticleSubcategory ArticleSubcategory {get; set;}
    }
```

And I have also 1 DTO:

```
 public class ArticleCategoryResult
    {
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public List<string> Subcategories { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to use AutoMapper to list the names of subcategories. I tried something like this but I get an empty list.

My Automapper code:

```
CreateMap<ArticleCategory, ArticleCategoryResult>()
              .ForMember(dst => dst.CategoryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MainCategoryName))
              .ForMember(dst => dst.IsActive, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsActive))
              .ForMember(dst => dst.Subcategories, src => src.MapFrom(mbr => mbr.ArticleCategorySubcategories.Select(x => x.ArticleSubcategory.SubcategoryName)));
```

Result on view as json:

```
{
  "categoryName": "Example category 6",
  "subcategories": [],
  "isActive": true
}
```

This is what my configuration looks like for these tables:

```
 public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ArticleCategorySubcategory> builder)
 {
            builder
                .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder
                .HasOne(x => x.ArticleCategory)
                .WithMany(x => x.ArticleCategorySubcategories)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArticleCategoryId);

            builder
                .HasOne(x => x.ArticleSubcategory)
                .WithMany(x => x.ArticleCategorySubcategories)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArticleSubcategoryId);
  }
```

How can I list the names of subcategories using AutoMapper?

Comment: I'm just wondering if adding `.Include(x=>x.ArticleSubcategory)` before your `.Select helps?

Comment: I think @GoldenAge is right .Addition , you must add it to your query before calling mapper. check the result after run query on db and before calling mapper . is ArticleSubcategory filled in object?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add `Include(x => x.ArticleCategorySubcategories).ThenInclude(x => x.ArticleSubcategory) ` in my query before calling mapper. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.Include(x=>x.ArticleSubcategory)` before your `.Select(..` as the related objects are not tracked and are treated as undefined.